# Reactnative Fusionchart fc-build-assets shows an error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, fusioncharts

When I run `npm run build:assets` it output below error:

```
sh: fc-build-assets: command not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
```

My Package.json is configured as below:

```
"build:assets": "fc-build-assets --fc-template ./assets/fusioncharts-tpl-ios.html --fc-library ./assets/fusioncharts"
```

Note. I'm working on a version upgrade of react-native-fusioncharts from 4.1.2 to 5.0.0. Since I couldn't find proper upgrade guide, I follow this one.
https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/getting-started/react-native/your-first-chart-using-react-native

Edit: `fc-build-assets` is no longer required in `react-native-fusioncharts: 5.0.0` so if you are upgrade it no need to worry about it.

Comment: The doc is not updated, please follow this guide  : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fusioncharts

The build command has been changed now, all are managed from metrocnfig file

Comment: Thanks, @Zapdos13 I got the same feedback from the Fusionchart support. Now working on it.